# Getting a character to be represented by an int 0-25

Tags: java, encryption, char, int

I'm working on a cryptography program that implements various traditional methods. For some of them it is best for my message to be represented as numbers 0-25. A is 0, B is 1, etc. This shift cipher is a case of that since you must take mod 26 for a wrap around. Also spaces and punctuation must be preserved.
Here is the code for the method that does the shift cipher:

```
public static void shift(char k, char eord)
{
    if(eord=='E' || eord=='e')
    {
        int [] mi= new int[mc.length];
        for(int i=0; i<mc.length; i++)
        {
            if ((mc[i]>='a' && mc[i]<='z') || (mc[i]>='A' && mc[i]<='Z'))
            {
                mi[i]=(int)(mc[i]+k);
                mi[i]=mi[i]%26;
                //mc[i]=(char)mi[i];
                //System.out.println(mi[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

mc is an array of characters that holds the message and eord is a char that will determine whether to run the algorithm to encrypt or decrypt. What I have the code do is check to make sure that mc[i] is a letter and then add the char k (the key) and then I type cast it into an integer so I can mod 26. Something does not work correctly because when I have a key of 'b' (1) and see what the integer representation is it is definitely not correct.  I also need to convert it back to a character when I'm done so I can give the user the plaintext/cipher text of the message.

Comment: the char `b` has an ASCII value of 98, so if you print `b` as an int, you will get 98. If you want that to be 1, you must subtract 97 from it. This will also make `a` = 0, `c` =  2, etc. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: What is `mc`?  This code looks awfully convoluted for what should be quite simple. Also, 0-25 does not allow you to represent a space or punctuation... probably not what you want.

Comment: @JimGarrison mc is an array of characters which hold the message. ie if the message was "hello" mc[0]='h', mc[1]='e' and so forth. I also do not need to change spaces and punctuation  hence why I only need the numbers 0-25. Also if I use just ASCII code values the cryptography methods will not work properly. 'A' and 'a' have to be treated "as the same thing"

Comment: @MegumiAi in that case you can do `mi[i]%32-1` to turn `A` and `a` into 0 etc.

Comment: Note: newline is already 10 (and possibly 13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an integer value of 0..25 of a character you need to make sure that you only get upper- or lowercase characters in the alphabet.

Let's assume lowercase. Then you can simply convert the characters to integer by subtracting the value of the `'a'` character. As the character values are ordered as in the normal alphabet, this will give `'a'` value of 0 and `'z'` value of 25... and  all the letters in between will get the correct value as well.

I'll show a lowercase version as I don't like shouting:

```
public class CharacterToZeroBasedIntegerRange {

    public static int characterToIntegerRange(char c) {
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'z') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Character with value %04X is not a letter", (int) c));
        }

        return c - 'a';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Hello world!".toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
        System.out.println(test);
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
            char c = test.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(characterToIntegerRange(c));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And then to turn the integer back to a character I would have a char function that had an int for the argument and added 'a' to the int correct?

Comment: Yep, reverse the algorithm and you're golden. You need to cast it though, as an `int` + a char will return an `int` instead of a `char` (so `(char) (v + 'a')` should do it).